# Device stops receiving notifications after 24 hours

Tags: android, parse-platform, push

I have an application in android and phonegap and I'm using Parse to send pushs.
Everything works fine when I install it: I can send and receive notifications.

After 5 hours, it starts to delay the pushs and after one day, it stops and I cant receive it anymore.

I see the notifications in dashboard but not in device.

Can someone give me a sugestion ?

Manifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.meeto1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

        <supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>


  <application
  android:name="com.example.meeto1.ParseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.meeto1.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />


<receiver android:name="com.example.meeto1.PushReceiver"
  android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" 
               android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

PushReceiver.java:

```
package com.example.meeto1;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
        public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("Push", "Clicked2");

          Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
          String message = extras != null ? extras.getString("com.parse.Data") : "";
          JSONObject jObject;
          try {
                  jObject = new JSONObject(message);
                  for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
                  {
                      Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, jObject.getString("alert"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                      toast.show();
                  }

          } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
          }

        }

        @Override
        protected Class<? extends Activity> getActivity(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.v("Parse", "getActivity called");
            return super.getActivity(context, intent);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.v("Parse", "onPushReceive called");
            super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.v("Parse", "onReceive Called");
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.meeto1;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.ParsePush;


public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        this.appView.addJavascriptInterface(new MainActivity(), "Android");
        this.appView.addJavascriptInterface(new MeusMetodos(), "MeusMetodos");
        this.appView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        Log.w(TAG, "App stopped");

        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.w(TAG, "App destoryed");

        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

ParseApplication.java

```
package com.example.meeto1;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.ParsePush;
import com.parse.PushService;

import android.app.Application;

public class ParseApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     Parse.initialize(this, "xxx", "xxx");
     ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("todosUsuarios");
     ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }  

}
```

Comment: Do you still see the Installation object for that device on Parse's dashboard (core > data tab)?

Comment: Yes, every time I install the app in one device, I can see an installation object in dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know I solved it.

In my Manifest,inside `<application>`, I'm using  the GCM Parse support and my notifications are working now:

```
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
 android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.example.meeto1" />
  </intent-filter>
```